# Cant switch shell to su

Tags: root-access, permissions, mount

I'm trying to edit my /init.rc file on my rooted Galaxy Pro.  And have accessed my device using SSH (to QuickSSH server on the device) over wifi.  The / mount is shown as readonly, so I tried to remount with option rw, but I get

```
mount: permission denied
```

The phone is rooted.  Why would this not work?  I issued the 'su' command but that made no difference.  whoami still shows

```
whoami: unknown uid 1010062
```

I know linux, but not android.  Come someone tell me how to switch to root?

Comment: May be the issue is with the shell implemented by QuickSSH. I use [Servers Ultimate Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro) for SSH and when I use `su` the UID does change to `0` and I can easily do `mount -o rw,remount /system /system`.

Comment: If the devices are on same LAN , maybe `adb shell` over Network Debugging is a better choice.